# Postgres slow query (slow index scan)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table with 3 million rows and 1.3GB in size. Running Postgres 9.3 on my laptop with 4GB RAM.

```
explain analyze
select act_owner_id from cnt_contacts where act_owner_id = 2
```

I have btree key on cnt_contacts.act_owner_id defined as:

```
CREATE INDEX cnt_contacts_idx_act_owner_id 
   ON public.cnt_contacts USING btree (act_owner_id, status_id);
```

The query runs in about 5 seconds

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on cnt_contacts  (cost=2598.79..86290.73 rows=6208 width=4) (actual time=5865.617..5875.302 rows=5444 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (act_owner_id = 2)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cnt_contacts_idx_act_owner_id  (cost=0.00..2597.24 rows=6208 width=0) (actual time=5865.407..5865.407 rows=5444 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (act_owner_id = 2)
Total runtime: 5875.684 ms"
```

Why is taking so long?

```
work_mem = 1024MB; 
shared_buffers = 128MB;
effective_cache_size = 1024MB
seq_page_cost = 1.0         # measured on an arbitrary scale
random_page_cost = 15.0         # same scale as above
cpu_tuple_cost = 3.0
```

Comment: What is the definition of the `cnt_contacts_idx_act_owner_id`  index?

Comment: CREATE INDEX cnt_contacts_idx_act_owner_id ON public.cnt_contacts
  USING btree (act_owner_id, status_id);

Comment: You should create another index just having `act_owner_id` at it.

Comment: won't help, tried with only act_owner_id as a key, the query results are same, no difference

Comment: Why did you increase random_page_cost that much? (The default is 4.0 if I'm not mistaken). That way you are telling Postgres that you have an incredible slow harddisk with a very high latency. And the cpu_tuple_cost seems also very strange (given that the default is 0.01). Even on my pretty old slow desktop lowering random_page_cost to 2.5 improved the execution plans Postgres was creating

Comment: And work_mem=1GB is absurd, too.

Comment: and why effective_cache_size has the same value as work_mem? it's insane.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, You have big table, index and long time execution plain for PG. Lets think about ways how to improve you plan and reduce time. You write and remove rows. PG write and remove tuples and table and index can be bloated. For good search PG loads index to shared buffer. And you need keep you index clean as possible. For selection PG reads to shared buffer and than search. Try to set up buffer memory and reduce index and table bloating, keep db cleaned.

What you do and think about:

1) Just check index duplicates and that you indexes have good selection:

```
 WITH table_scans as (
    SELECT relid,
        tables.idx_scan + tables.seq_scan as all_scans,
        ( tables.n_tup_ins + tables.n_tup_upd + tables.n_tup_del ) as writes,
                pg_relation_size(relid) as table_size
        FROM pg_stat_user_tables as tables
),
all_writes as (
    SELECT sum(writes) as total_writes
    FROM table_scans
),
indexes as (
    SELECT idx_stat.relid, idx_stat.indexrelid,
        idx_stat.schemaname, idx_stat.relname as tablename,
        idx_stat.indexrelname as indexname,
        idx_stat.idx_scan,
        pg_relation_size(idx_stat.indexrelid) as index_bytes,
        indexdef ~* 'USING btree' AS idx_is_btree
    FROM pg_stat_user_indexes as idx_stat
        JOIN pg_index
            USING (indexrelid)
        JOIN pg_indexes as indexes
            ON idx_stat.schemaname = indexes.schemaname
                AND idx_stat.relname = indexes.tablename
                AND idx_stat.indexrelname = indexes.indexname
    WHERE pg_index.indisunique = FALSE
),
index_ratios AS (
SELECT schemaname, tablename, indexname,
    idx_scan, all_scans,
    round(( CASE WHEN all_scans = 0 THEN 0.0::NUMERIC
        ELSE idx_scan::NUMERIC/all_scans * 100 END),2) as index_scan_pct,
    writes,
    round((CASE WHEN writes = 0 THEN idx_scan::NUMERIC ELSE idx_scan::NUMERIC/writes END),2)
        as scans_per_write,
    pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) as index_size,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) as table_size,
    idx_is_btree, index_bytes
    FROM indexes
    JOIN table_scans
    USING (relid)
),
index_groups AS (
SELECT 'Never Used Indexes' as reason, *, 1 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    idx_scan = 0
    and idx_is_btree
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Low Scans, High Writes' as reason, *, 2 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    scans_per_write <= 1
    and index_scan_pct < 10
    and idx_scan > 0
    and writes > 100
    and idx_is_btree
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Seldom Used Large Indexes' as reason, *, 3 as grp
FROM index_ratios
WHERE
    index_scan_pct < 5
    and scans_per_write > 1
    and idx_scan > 0
    and idx_is_btree
    and index_bytes > 100000000
UNION ALL
SELECT 'High-Write Large Non-Btree' as reason, index_ratios.*, 4 as grp 
FROM index_ratios, all_writes
WHERE
    ( writes::NUMERIC / ( total_writes + 1 ) ) > 0.02
    AND NOT idx_is_btree
    AND index_bytes > 100000000
ORDER BY grp, index_bytes DESC )
SELECT reason, schemaname, tablename, indexname,
    index_scan_pct, scans_per_write, index_size, table_size
FROM index_groups;
```

2) Check if you have tables and index bloating?

```
     SELECT
        current_database(), schemaname, tablename, /*reltuples::bigint, relpages::bigint, otta,*/
        ROUND((CASE WHEN otta=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE sml.relpages::FLOAT/otta END)::NUMERIC,1) AS tbloat,
        CASE WHEN relpages < otta THEN 0 ELSE bs*(sml.relpages-otta)::BIGINT END AS wastedbytes,
      iname, /*ituples::bigint, ipages::bigint, iotta,*/
      ROUND((CASE WHEN iotta=0 OR ipages=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE ipages::FLOAT/iotta END)::NUMERIC,1) AS ibloat,
      CASE WHEN ipages < iotta THEN 0 ELSE bs*(ipages-iotta) END AS wastedibytes
    FROM (
      SELECT
        schemaname, tablename, cc.reltuples, cc.relpages, bs,
        CEIL((cc.reltuples*((datahdr+ma-
          (CASE WHEN datahdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE datahdr%ma END))+nullhdr2+4))/(bs-20::FLOAT)) AS otta,
        COALESCE(c2.relname,'?') AS iname, COALESCE(c2.reltuples,0) AS ituples, COALESCE(c2.relpages,0) AS ipages,
        COALESCE(CEIL((c2.reltuples*(datahdr-12))/(bs-20::FLOAT)),0) AS iotta -- very rough approximation, assumes all cols
      FROM (
        SELECT
          ma,bs,schemaname,tablename,
          (datawidth+(hdr+ma-(CASE WHEN hdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE hdr%ma END)))::NUMERIC AS datahdr,
          (maxfracsum*(nullhdr+ma-(CASE WHEN nullhdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE nullhdr%ma END))) AS nullhdr2
        FROM (
          SELECT
            schemaname, tablename, hdr, ma, bs,
            SUM((1-null_frac)*avg_width) AS datawidth,
            MAX(null_frac) AS maxfracsum,
            hdr+(
              SELECT 1+COUNT(*)/8
              FROM pg_stats s2
              WHERE null_frac<>0 AND s2.schemaname = s.schemaname AND s2.tablename = s.tablename
            ) AS nullhdr
          FROM pg_stats s, (
            SELECT
              (SELECT current_setting('block_size')::NUMERIC) AS bs,
              CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(v,12,3) IN ('8.0','8.1','8.2') THEN 27 ELSE 23 END AS hdr,
              CASE WHEN v ~ 'mingw32' THEN 8 ELSE 4 END AS ma
            FROM (SELECT version() AS v) AS foo
          ) AS constants
          GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
        ) AS foo
      ) AS rs
      JOIN pg_class cc ON cc.relname = rs.tablename
      JOIN pg_namespace nn ON cc.relnamespace = nn.oid AND nn.nspname = rs.schemaname AND nn.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      LEFT JOIN pg_index i ON indrelid = cc.oid
      LEFT JOIN pg_class c2 ON c2.oid = i.indexrelid
    ) AS sml
    ORDER BY wastedbytes DESC
```

3) Do you clean unused tuples from hard disk? Is it time for vacuum?

```
SELECT 
    relname AS TableName
    ,n_live_tup AS LiveTuples
    ,n_dead_tup AS DeadTuples
FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

4) Think about that. If you have 10 records in db and 8 of 10 have id = 2 thats mean you have bad selectivity of index and in this way PG will scan all 8 records. But of you try to use id != 2 index will work good. Try to set index with good selection.

5) Use proper column type got you data. If you can use less kb type for you column just convert it.

6) Just check you DB and condition. Check this for start going [page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance)
Just try to see that you have in data base unused data in tables, indexes must be cleaned, check selectivity for you indexes. Try use other brin indexes for data, try to recreate indexes.

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting 5444 records scattered over a 1.3 GB table on a laptop.  How long do you *expect* that to take?

It looks like your index is not cached, either because it can't be sustained in the cache, or because this is the first time you used that part of it.  What happens if you run the exact same query repeatedly?  The same query but with a different constant?

running the query under "explain (analyze,buffers)" would be helpful to get additional information, particularly if you turned track_io_timing on first.

Comment: Nice hint on using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ...` which gives output of shared buffer hits. It helped me realize that increasing the size of shared buffer boosts performance, if the bottle-neck is really there, which in my case was true.